# No sound output from kivy.core.audio

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

The problem I am having from kivy.core.audio is no sound output from my speakers (the speakers are fine). The file format I am trying to play is an mp3. I have copied the code from the api documentation from the official kivy website but it just wont output any sound. The file is being accepted into an object as you will see in the output but no sound comes out.

```
# hungarian_tutor.py

''' A program to teach Hungarian translated from English '''
import kivy
kivy.require("1.11.1")

from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from random import choice

alphabet = ("a", "á", "b", "c", "cs", "d", "dz", "dzs", "e", "é", "f", "g", "gy", "h", "i", "í", "j", "k", "l", "ly",
             "m", "n", "ny", "o", "ó", "ö", "ő", "p", "q", "r", "s", "sz", "t", "ty", "u", "ú", "ü", "ű", "v", "w", "x",
             "y", "z", "zs")

basic_phrases = [["Hello", "Szia", "hello.mp3"],["Good Morning", "Translate*", "good-morning.mp3"]]

phrase = choice(basic_phrases)
eng = phrase[0]; hun = phrase[1]; hun_audio = phrase[2]
audio = SoundLoader.load("audio/" + hun_audio)
if audio:
    audio.play()
```

Output:

```
 C:\Users\jhowd\PycharmProjects\hungarian_tutor\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/jhowd/PycharmProjects/hungarian_tutor/hungarian_tutor.py
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\jhowd\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-05-14_27.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.1.18
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.1.10
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.1.12
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.1.23
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\jhowd\PycharmProjects\hungarian_tutor\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.6.8 (tags/v3.6.8:3c6b436a57, Dec 24 2018, 00:16:47) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\jhowd\PycharmProjects\hungarian_tutor\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [AudioGstplayer] Using Gstreamer 1.16.0.0
[INFO   ] [Audio       ] Providers: audio_gstplayer, audio_sdl2 (audio_ffpyplayer ignored)
[WARNING] Deprecated property "<AliasProperty name=filename>" of object "<kivy.core.audio.audio_gstplayer.SoundGstplayer object at 0x000002BF6A5722B8>" was accessed, it will be removed in a future version

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

`audio.play()` immediately returns after starts the sound.

Put `import time;time.sleep(audio.length)` to the end of the file.